# Multi column list in windows 8 phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a app to display tabular list (ID, Name, Lname) in the windows 8 phone. 
My XAML file is as below

```
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneSemitransparentBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,5" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderBrush}" />
                    <!-- Replace the default item template with a basic template that does not highlight selected items. -->
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="SummaryStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>


            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock  Text="ID" Width="100" />
                <TextBlock  Text="Name" Width="150"/>
                <TextBlock  Text="LName"  Width="150"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <ScrollViewer Margin="-5,13,3,36" Height="558">
                <ListBox Name="lstBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          Height="380" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,25,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FName}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LName}" />

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

            </ScrollViewer>

        </Grid>
```

and I call the below code on the button click even

```
        List<Customers> cust = new List<Customers>();
        cust.Add(new Customers(1, "Ganesh", "S"));
        cust.Add(new Customers(2, "Shan", "S"));
        cust.Add(new Customers(3, "Anjan", "A"));
        lstBox.ItemsSource = cust;
```

But, it does not display the list it is just showing the column. These customer name should display as in windows 8 phone

---

ID                  Name                     LName

---

```
1                  Ganesh                   S
2                  Shan                     S
3                  Anjan                    A
```

What is missing in the code? or What should I follow while to display multi column list in windows 8 phone?

Comment: Do you need this `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` in the markup, you are assigning it in code behind

Comment: I am new to this Windows 8 phone app development. In my previous try, I have included the List collection name with this {Binding} property. Now I have removed this. If you feel, to change this, will help to my question, please go ahead.

Comment: Can you try by removing the columndefintions you are actually using only the first one, the others are taking up the space

Answer (score 0):

You have defined three columns but the `StackPanel` is placed in the first column (default behavior), hence i guess that you are not able to view the data.

Or probably you can assign the header `TextBlocks` to the grid (remove the stackpanel) and within the itemtemplate define another grid with similar width which should help you achieve the layout.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<TextBlock  Text="ID" Width="100" Grid.Column="0"/>
<TextBlock  Text="Name" Width="150" Grid.Column="1"/>
<TextBlock  Text="LName"  Width="150" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

and then your template like

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Grid >
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Grid.Column="0"/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding FName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding LName}" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

(not tested code just re arranged as per your post) hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. I tried as per you suggestion, but still it is not displaying any value in the list. It just display the header information.

Comment: Ok, just add two rowdefintion the header would be Row=0 and the `ListBox` Row=1 and ColSpan=3

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Grid` inside the `StackPanel`. In that create a `column`.

Here it looks like:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="-5,13,3,36" Height="558">
            <ListBox Name="lstBox" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
      Height="380" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,25,0,0" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                           <Grid>
                               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Specify width"  />
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Specify width"  />
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Specify width"  />
                               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" Grid.Column="0" />
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding FName}" Grid.Column="1" />
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding LName}" Grid.Column="2" />
                           </Grid> 
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
```